# Button won't work (kivy) (python)

Tags: python, button, kivy

can someone explain to me why this button won't work? When i run the game the button is visible but i can't press it.

```
class game_widget(Widget):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(game_widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    with self.canvas:
        Color(*sky_color)
        Rectangle(pos=(0, 0), size=self.size)
    with self.canvas:
        Color(*grass_color)
        Rectangle(pos=(0,0), size=(800,75))
    with self.canvas:
        Label(text='Funky Chicken', font_size='50sp', pos=(360, 400))
    with self.canvas:
        self.main_menu_button = Button(text='Play', pos=(360, 200))
        self.main_menu_button.bind(on_press = self.main_menu_button_callback)

    layout = FloatLayout()
    layout.add_widget(self.main_menu_button)

def main_menu_button_callback(self, obj):
    click_sound.play()

class FunkyChickenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return game_widget(size=Window.size)
```

Apparently it seems like the button is some sort of canvas only. Working example:

```
self.main_menu_button = Button(text='Play', font_size=25, pos=(360, 200))
self.main_menu_button.bind(on_press=self.main_menu_button_callback)

    self.add_widget(self.main_menu_button)

def main_menu_button_callback(self, obj):
    click_sound.play()
    print("button working")`
```

Comment: Do you received any error ?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut no, i do not receive any sort of error.

Comment: I may be wrong, but perhaps your callback is executed but the sound is too low or something like that? If you try a `print`, is there something in the standard output? Also, where is defined the variable `click_sound`?

Comment: @AnthonyB print did not work. It said nothing in the console when i pressed the button.